# better than kingship for you OR for you better than kingship

Tags: grammar

Where should we place the complement 'for you' in the predicative? Such as in this:

> It is better than kingship for you.

Is the right construction? Or, 'for you' should initiate the sentence? Like in this:

> For you it is better than the kingship.

Please note that in the two constructions, my concern is to find myself sounding more natural.

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatically correct. The thing that you want to emphasize needs to be at the front of the sentence. If you are making a comment that is applicable to only one person, you start with "For you...". If the emphasis is on "better", you start with "It is better"...

---

Note that **[kingship](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kingship)** is a pretty uncommon word, and probably doesn't mean what you think: kingship relates to the duty, rather than the privilege: it is not something to be enjoyed. Also, it is uncountable, so you don't put **the** in front of it when referring to it as a general concept.

Comment: Well, maybe there are worse works than being king. ;-P

Comment: @RubioRic Apart from for Charles I, Louis X1V, Faisal II etc...

Comment: Yes, but we've got a saying here in South Spain, "que les quiten lo bailao" [More o less: you can execute them but they have enjoyed fully their lifes and you can't do anything about it]

Comment: @userr2684291 agreed, but probably not in this context.